# Irreducible representations of the unitriangular group

Tags: characters, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Hi,
I wonder how much is known about the irreducible representations of the nxn unitriangular group over a finite field with q elements.
I know that all characterdegrees are a power of q and all degrees which occur are known.But what is known about the irreducible representations or the complete charactertable at least for small values of n?For example is the charactertable for n=3 known?
Thanks for helping

Comment: I know this is a super-old question, but Diaconis et al looked at almost exactly this question: https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04160

Answer (score 5):

Not much—the theory of individual irreducible representations is a 'wild' problem, in some technical sense (that I don't know).  My understanding, which comes entirely from informal conversations with Nat Thiem, is that the state of the art is to lump together representations until you get more nicely behaved objects called *supercharacters*.  As far as I know, the original definitions are due to 
[André](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869385711878) (who calls them ‘basic characters’) and Yan, and there is an explicit [supercharacter table](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869301987344).

Answer (score 4):

I think you might enjoy Kirillov's [survey article](http://bit.ly/ki7ACg) which describes [Orbit method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_method) approach in this particular case.  Also, if I recall correctly, [this article](http://math.ucsd.edu/~eariasca/papers/UniRW.pdf) by Ery Arias-Castro, Persi Diaconis and Richard Stanley gives a very readable introduction to the state of art on the conjugacy classes and characters.

Answer (score 2):

Let *q* = *p*<sup>*k*</sup> be a prime power, *n* be a positive integer, and *U* be a Sylow *p*-subgroup of GL(*n*, *q*).

For *n* = 1, *U* = 1 is the trivial group and its character table is known (just the identity/principal character).

For *n* = 2, *U* = *q* is elementary abelian of order *q*, and its character table is known (just *q* distinct linear characters).

For *n* = 3, *U* is similar to an extra-special *q*-group, and the same calculation works to find its ordinary character table.  A sketch: *U*/[*U*, *U*] is elementary abelian of order *q*<sup>2</sup>, giving *q*<sup>2</sup> (known) linear characters.  Since |*U*|−[*U* : [*U*, *U*]] = *q*<sup>3</sup>−*q*<sup>2</sup> = *q*<sup>2</sup>(*q*−1), and the degrees of the irreducible characters are powers of *q* and their squares sum to |*U*|, one must have the remaining characters have degree *q* and there are q−1 of them. Since *U* is monomial, each of these characters is induced from a (non-principal) linear character on a subgroup of index *q* (which must be abelian).  Hence each such character vanishes off of Z(*U*), and acts in the expected way on its center.  That is, take any non-identity irreducible character θ of Z(*U*), there are *q*−1 of these, and then define χ(*g*) = q⋅θ(*g*) if *g* in Z(*U*) and χ(*g*) = 0 otherwise.  Personally I just execute the definition of induced character and then check the norm of χ is (χ,χ)=1, but I think there are cleverer ways.

I think prime powers *q* for higher *n* work similarly, but I'm not very familiar with even the prime case for *n* ≥ 4.

Answer (score 2):

An earlier answer tells you what happens when $n=3$.  This is a special case of the Heisenberg group (at least in odd characteristic; not sure otherwise), any exposition of which might be illuminating if you're looking for more context.

More generally, Boyarchenko has recently [shown](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.2742) that all representations of "nilpotent algebra" groups, of which unitriangular groups are a special case, are induced from one-dimensional representations of "nilpotent algebra" subgroups.  While this fact is not a magical tool for computing the full character table (a wild problem, as LS says), it's pretty interesting, and might allow you to work out the $n=4$ case if you were interested in such an exercise.

Comment: thanks,i know that result.it would be interesting to know what has been done for n=4,before i try ;) I know for example that all characterdegrees with their multiplicity is known.can someone by the way say what exactly "wild" means?

Comment: Since this question is about finite algebra groups, it should be pointed out that the result that says that any irrep of an algebra group over a finite field is induced from a 1-dim'l rep of an algebra subgroup is due to Halasi. Boyarchenko has given a new proof valid also for algebra groups over local fields.

Comment: A somewhat relevant question I'm curious about: if we work over $\mathbb{R}$ instead of a finite field, the problem of determining the irreps of the group remains just as "wild"?

Comment: @AStansinski:  You're right, I should have mentioned Halasi, but have local fields on the brain.

Comment: @trew, I *believe* that the sense in which the classification is wild is that discussed in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10481/when-is-a-classification-problem-wild.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found out about the characters when n=4.I dont know if thats interesting and how to get the actuall irreducible characters then.Maybe someone has an idea:
There are $ q^{3} $ linear and from http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/~marial/uni1.published.pdf there are $q^{3}-q $ characters of degree q and $q(q-1)$ characters of degree $q^{2}$.
Now lets look at the characters of $G/Z(G)=1+J/J^{3}$ ,where Z(G) is the center of the group and J are the lower triangular matrices with zeros on the diagonal.This is again an algebragroup,so we have:
$q^{5}=q^{3}+aq^{2}+bq^{4}$,where a is the number of the degree q characters of G/Z(G) and b the number of degree $q^{2}$ characters.
Assume $ \phi$ is a degree $q^{2}$ character in G/Z(G),then $ [ \phi_{Z(G/Z(G))} , \psi] \neq 0$ ,for a linear character $\psi $ of Z(G/Z(G)).But then since $\psi$ is G/Z(G) invariant as a character of the center and using Clifford: $\phi_{Z(G/Z(G))}=q^{2} \psi$ and then $ \psi^{G/Z(G)} = q^{2} \phi +...$ which is not possible because of $ \psi^{G/Z(G)}(1)=q^{3} < q^{4} =q^{2} \phi(1)$.
So we have b=0 and a=q^{3}-q from $q^{5}=q^{3}+aq^{2}$.So all the degree q characters of G are also the degree q characters of G/Z(G).
Let now $\chi$ be a character of degree q of G/Z(G) then we can choose a linear character $\psi$ of Z(G/Z(G)) with $[\chi_{Z(G/Z(G))} ,\psi] \neq 0 $ and again as above: $ \psi^{G/Z(G)} = q^{2} \chi +...$
Since $(1_{Z(G/Z(G))})^{G/Z(G)}$ has all linear characters as constituents $\psi^{G/Z(G)}$ can only have degree q irreducible constituents.So for all(there are $q^{2}-1$ such) the nontrivial linear characters $\psi_k $ of Z(G/Z(G)),we have : 
$ (\psi_k)^{G/Z(G)} = q \sum\limits_{i=1}^{q} {\chi_i}$.
Similary one can show that for all nontrivial linear characters $\vartheta_k $ of Z(G) one has:
$(\vartheta_k)^{G}=q \sum\limits_{i=1}^{q} {\phi_i} $,where $\phi_i$ are degree-$q^{2}$ characters of G.