# Representation theory of p-groups in particular upper tringular matrices over F_p 

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, gr.group-theory

Finite [p-groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group) - have p^n elements by definition. According to WP there is rich structure theory.

**Question:** How far is representation theory of p-groups is understood?

In case this question is too broad let me restrict it to upper triangular matrices over F_q.
What is known about its irreps ? Dimensions ? Constructions ? Action of Out(G) ? Characters ?

E.g.  4x4 matrices over F_2 - this group has order 64. So dimensions of irreps over C are 1,2,4 by trivial reasons that 1) dim | order of group and 2) \sum dim^2 = order of group. 
Is it possible to illustrate the general theory (if it exists) on this example to compute number
of different irreps of for this group ?

---

Remarks:

Notation: let me denote U_n(F_q) = upper triangular matrices over F_q  with units on the diagonal.

Some trivial examples: U_2(F_2) = Z/2; U_3(F_2) = D_8 - dihedral group with 8 elements.

Remark: U_n(F_q) is p-Sylow  subgroup of GL_n(F_q). Over F_2 it will also be Borel subgroup.

Comment: Googling on "representation theory of p-groups": http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.0637 http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/craven/docs/lectures/pgroups.pdf http://scholarsresearchlibrary.com/aasr-vol2-iss6/AASR-2010-2-6-15-27.pdf http://grt.epfl.ch/ln.pdf

Comment: As a part of my PhD thesis, I have done some research on $F_p[G]$-modules, where $G$ is a cyclic $p$-group. Although it is restricted to a very specific $p$-groups, it may be useful/inspiring for your work. You can find my results in the article titled "MODULE HOMOMORPHISMS OF GROUP ALGEBRAS OF CYCLIC p-GROUPS IN CHARACTERISTIC p". It is freely available in the internet.

Comment: @Vahid Thank you! Googling "representation theory of upper triangular matrices p-groups"  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.100.4729  http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Kirillov_orbit_method_for_finite_Lazard_Lie_group http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_unitriangular_matrix_group_of_degree_three_over_a_finite_field http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Unitriangular_matrix_group:UT(3,3) http://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.4935.pdf http://www.scribd.com/doc/88321666/17/Nilpotent-groups-and-p-groups 

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2674 Representations of Finite Unipotent Linear Groups by the Method of Clusters Ning Yan http://web.ceu.hu/math/People/Alumni_and_Friends/Alumni/Zoltan_HALASI_Thesis.pdf Zoltan Halasi On the representations of solvable linear groups

Comment: Involutions in $S_n$ and associated coadjoint orbits
A. N. Panov http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3022 Coadjoint orbits of the group $UT(7,K)$ M.V. Ignatev, A.N. Panov http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603649

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Unitriangular_matrix_group:UT(4,2) Special page on groupprops for U(4,2) 

Comment: Eric Marberg papers in arXiv lots of on rep-theory of UT http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+Marberg/0/1/0/all/0/1

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501332 Coadjoint orbits for $A_{n-1}^+, B_{n}^{+}$, and $D_{n}^{+}$

Shantala Mukherjee

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68207/irreducible-representations-of-the-unitriangular-group

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99126/conjugacy-classes-of-a-p-group?rq=1

Comment: http://www.math.kth.se/~boij/kandexjobbVT11/Material/pgroups.pdf Nice text about p^3, p^4 groups


Comment: Related question:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126932/finite-unipotent-groups-references

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(This answer is only about *representation theory over $\mathbb{C}$*, that is, character theory.) You should take a look at §26: *Characters of $p$-groups* of Bertram Huppert's book *Character Theory of Finite Groups*. In particular, it contains a proof of Isaacs' results that the set of character degrees of a $p$-group is rather arbitrary (Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 96 (1986), p.551-552, [doi: 10.2307/2046302](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2046302)) and that character degrees of groups of the form $1+ \mathbf{J}(A)$, where $A$ is a finite algebra over the field $F$ with $q$ elements, are powers of $q$ (J. Algebra 177 (1995), p. 708-730, [doi: 10.1006/jabr.1995.1325](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1995.1325)), and a proof that the character degrees of $U_n(F_q)$ are the powers $q^i$ for $0\leq i\leq \lfloor \frac{(n-1)^2}{4}\rfloor$. (A result of Huppert, Arch. Math. 59 (1992), p. 313-318, [doi: 10.1007/BF01197044](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01197044).)
There is also an elaborate theory of "supercharacters" and "superclasses" for the upper triangular group (and other groups). A good place to start reading is, I think (but I'm not an expert), the paper of Diaconis and Isaacs: *Supercharacters and superclasses for algebra groups*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 360 (2008), p.2359-2392, [MR2373317](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2373317) ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-07-04365-6)). There are, by now, many papers about the character theory of the upper triangular group and related topics, which is in part motivated by Higman's conjecture that for every $n$, the number of conjugacy classes of $U_n(F_q)$ is a polynomial in $q$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: Thank you very much for yours kind answer ! Let me ask something. You write that dim(irreps)<= floor[ (n-1)^2/4], is it correct, I mean "floor" not "ceil" rounding ? So in particular if n=4, p= 2 we get [9/4] = 2, so this means that dims of irreps are 1,2.  So 4 is forbidden. If i understand correctly G/[G,G] in this case contain 8 elements. So we see that there should be 8*dim1 + 16*dim2. So in total there should be 24 irreps and same number of conjugacy classes. Does it sounds reasonable ? Or I miscalculated ? 

Comment: @Alexander Chervov: for $n=4$, you get $\lfloor 9/4 \rfloor = 2$, correct, but this means that the dims of the irreps are $q^0$, $q^1$ and $q^2$, so for $q=2$ they are $1$, $2$ and $4$. There are $q^3$ dim 1's, $q^3-q$ dim $q$'s and $q^2-q$ dim $q^2$'s.

Comment: Ooops, too much thinking ))... Thank you ! How did you get  "q3−q dim q's and q2−q dim q2's" ?

Comment: $G=U_4(F_q)$ has center of order $q$ and $G/Z(G)$ has center of order $q^2$ and index $q^3$, so that the irreps of $G/Z(G)$ have dim at most $q$. So $G/Z(G)$ must have  $q^3-q$ irreps of dim $q$. Finally, one needs to see that irreps where $Z(G)$ is not in the kernel have dimension $q^2$. If such an irrep had dim $q$, then it would have to be induced from a linear character of a subgroup of order $q^5$ (since $p$-groups are monomial), but $Z(G)$ is contained in the derived subgroup of every subgroup of order $q^5$, contradiction.  

Comment: Thank you very much ! How to you see "so that the irreps of G/Z(G) have dim at most q" and "So G/Z(G) must have q3−q irreps of dim q." ? Also this seems to appeal to some background which is not known for me "If such an irrep had dim q, then it would have to be induced from a linear character of a subgroup of order q5  --||WHY?||-- (since p-groups are monomial)--||?||--, but Z(G) is contained in the derived subgroup of every subgroup of order q5, contradiction. "  

Comment: By the way I've found page about UT(4,2)  http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Unitriangular_matrix_group:UT(4,2)  its count of conj. classes 2q^3+q^2-2q agrees with yours count of irreps number 

Comment: It is a general fact that $\chi(1)^2\leq |G:Z(G)|$ for any irred. character $\chi$ of a group $G$ (see Isaacs' book on character theory, Corollary 2.30). I apply this to $G/Z(G)$. Since $|(G/Z(G)):Z(G/Z(G))|=q^3$, irreps of $G/Z(G)$ have dim at most $q$. Since $|G/Z(G)|=$ sum of squares of the dims of the irreps, and we have $q^3=|G/[G,G]|$ irreps of dim 1, one can compute the number of irreps of dim $q$.  
A monomial group is a group where every character is induced from a linear character, and nilpotent groups are known to be monomial (see, for example, Corollary 6.14 in Isaacs' book).

Comment: Do you rely on the fact that all q-dim irreps of G comes from G/Z(G) ? If yes how to justify it? If not I do not quite understand: how do you get " one can compute the number of irreps of dim q "  ?

Comment: Yes, in this special family of groups every irrep of dim $q$ comes from $G/Z(G)$, that is, $Z(G)$ is contained in the kernel. I already mentioned this in my second comment to this answer: First, every irred. char. of a $p$-group is induced from a linear char. If $\chi\in \operatorname{Irr}(G)$ has $\chi(1)=q$, then $\chi=\lambda^G$ and $\lambda\in \operatorname{Lin}(N)$, where $|G:N|=\chi(1)=q$. So $|N|=q^5$ and $N$ is non-abelian and one can show that $Z(G)\leq [N,N]$, so $Z(G)\leq \ker(\lambda)$. But then also $Z(G)\leq \ker(\chi)$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much !   Might be interesting: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_unitriangular_matrix_group:UT(4,p)

Answer (score 6):

It is already a notoriously difficult problem to determine the number of conjugacy classes of elements of the group of upper unitriangular $n \times n$ matrices over the field of $q$ elements, when $n$ gets moderately large.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Indeed it seems I got too much optimism from WP-article... 

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm only starting to learn representation theory, but here's a thought about irreps. Forgove me if it seems trivial.

I think that a finite $p$-group always has only one irreducible representation over $F_p$ - the trivial one-dimensional representation. Here's why.

Let $F$ be a field with characteristic $p$ and let $G \leqslant \mathrm{GL}\left( n, F \right)$ be a finite irreducible $p$-group of matrices over $F$. Let $g$ be an element from the center of $G$.

Clearly, $g^{p^m}-1 = 0$ for some positive integer $m$. Since we are in characteristic $p$, it follows that $(g-1)^{p^m} = 0$. Therefore $\ker (g-1) \neq 0$. Now, since $g-1$ commutes with every element of $G$, $\ker (g-1)$ is a $G$-invariant subspace. Remember that $G$ is irreducible, which means that $g-1 = 0$.

So, we have proved that the center of $G$ is trivial, therefore $G$ itself is also trivial, qed.

PS: I am not sure, but maybe you could try googling "Modular representation theory" and "Brauer characters": I think I saw these things mentioned somewhere in connection with a similar question.

Comment:  Спасибо!   Welcome to MO. It might be related to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106543/p-adic-representations-of-groups  .It seems that over complex numbers problem is difficult.

Comment: Now that I've re-read your question, I see that "over $F_p$" in your question means "triangular matrices over $F_p$", not "representations over $F_p$". My answer totally useless then, sorry.

Comment: @Dan Shved do not worry, I was also interested about F_p although the main case for me is C.