# Shape of axioms in algebraic structures

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, model-theory, universal-algebra, algebraic-systems

When defining algebraic structures (like monoids, groups, etc...), are there some constraints on the shape of the axioms, for the structure to have good properties that we implicitly use in many proofs (like behaving well with respect to morphisms and quotients)?

For instance, is the following axiom acceptable, in a structure equipped with a unary function $f$ and a binary operator $\circ$:
$$\forall x, \text{ if }x\circ x=x\text{ then } f(x)=x.$$

More specifically, does it make sense to study varieties generated by (subclasses of) such classes of objects, even if the class of structures so defined is not a variety, since this axiom is not an equation?

Comment: *** Be my guest. ***

Comment: In the model theory of first-order logic, of course any kind of axioms are allowed and studied. Yet, often one can say much more when the axiomatizations have a special form. In universal algebra, for example, one often fruitfully restricts to equational axiomatizations, leading to the concept of a variety: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra#Varieties

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to be more specific. I am in fact interested specifically in varieties, but I need such an axiom for the general structure.

Comment: A variety is a class of structures, not a single structure (and I see that the Wikipedia page could be made more clear about this---someone should edit it), so  it doesn't make sense to say that "the whole structure is a variety" or "is not a variety". If you are defining a class of structures that cannot be defined by an equational theory, then you do not have a variety. But you do have a first-order definable class of structures $\text{Mod}(T)$, the class of models of a first-order theory $T$, and this is what much of model theory is about.

Comment: There is a descriptive term which I have forgotten which I will call x. It might be "representation" but I don't think so.  Birkhoff's HSP theorem is an x theorem, as is the one which says the class of models axiomatized by Horn sentences (eq. 1 implies eq. 2) is a quasivariety, a class closed under cetain algebraic constructions.  There are many x theorems in Model Theory.  Solve for x and I think you will have a general answer to your question.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins : yes, I meant the class of all structures $M$ defined by these axioms is not a variety. But then, does it make sense to say that adding new equations defines varieties of structures M (i.e. once we accepted the original axioms, we still say that equations define varieties).

Comment: The specific example you gave is an example of what category theorists call an essentially algebraic theory, where partially defined operations (with domains specified as loci of equations of previously given operations) may be admitted. The theory of categories is an example of an essentially algebraic theory. Categories of models of (finitary) essentially algebraic theories are characterized as locally finitely presentable categories. See the book on Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories by Adamek and Rosicky.

Comment: I am a little surprised this was shut down so quickly. Meta: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/538/2926

Comment: @YCor I've removed the "relational-structures" tag - I don't see any role of relational structures here, and in fact the question seems to be implicitly focusing on *non*-relational structures.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you might have commented before editing... one can view every $n$-ary law as a $(n+1)$-ary relation (with explicitly telling it's a law with respect to, say, the $0$-th variable). Thus I view universal algebra is a particular case of the realm of relational structures, and relational structures as the general framework for model theory. (Removing the tag sounds to me like saying that **pointed** topological spaces don't fit in the framework/tag "topological-spaces".)

Comment: @YCor That seems way too broad to be useful (especially given that "model theory" already exists as a tag); also, it seems to only be used about 12 times, each of them added by you. Is this really a useful tag? That said, if you revert I won't re-revert.

Comment: @NoahSchweber the problem with 'model-theory' is that it's first-order-logic-oriented. I created the tag recently in order to have a non-logic-motivated name for this broad but useful notion. I think one of the reasons which made model-theory papers uneasily accessible to me for a long time is that the framework (namely relational structure in the broadest interpretation) is quite implicit and not considered as interesting for itself. (Group theory is quite the opposite, we spend months to dissect the definition, a whole subdomain is to construct exotic examples, etc.)

Comment: @YCor But if it's *that* broad, what *doesn't* fall under the "relational-structures" heading? At a glance, *everything* seems like a relational structure (at least if you allow infinitary relations).

Comment: @NoahSchweber are all questions tagged "set-theory" because there's a set ? Are all questions about rings tagged "gr.group-theory" because of the additive group? No. This tag purports to be useful when it's a natural framework in its generality. For instance, a model-theory question about some specific context (groups, fields) doesn't fit. This question definitely fits. A few questions in model theory would fit, e.g. "is there a structure such...". I guess that certainly more than 12 questions fit (I did a quite rough search then) but not a huge number, probably less than 'universal-algebra'.

Comment: @YCor Honestly it really doesn't make any sense to me as a tag, but we should probably stop discussing this in the comments.

Comment: @NoahSchweber (for some reason it refuses to move to chat) I don't really see your point (if any, since you initially removed the tag as not general enough, then say it's too general... the only common denominator I can feel is that you don't like it). Anyway, let me mention that an example of a question where I'd find it useful is precisely [your question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116155/) where it's a natural framework.

Answer (score 10):

This is what is known as an equational Horn clause.  It is an implication between two equations.  It is a special case of what is called a near equational theory, which is one with operations and partial operations, the latter having domains given by equations using the ordinary (total) operations, plus equations involving the partial and total operations.  There is an apparent generalization in which you allow partial operations whose domains are given by equations involving partial operations, but it turns out not to be more general.

A good example is the category of (small) categories in which the domain of the composition operation is given equationally in terms of the total operations of domain and codomain.  This is discussed in detail in ``Category Theory for Computing Science'', available free at http://www.math.mcgill.ca/triples/Barr-Wells-ctcs.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

x = "preservation".

Usually one is motivated to study a structure because it
serves as a model for something of interest.  Likewise a
certain statement or class of statements may have nice
consequences for its class of models.  It is uncommon
to say 'I want to build this structure, but only if I can
characterize it with regular identities or in iambic
pentameter."  Preservation theorems are the family
of theorems that relate the shape of a characterizing
language/theory to the shape of the constructions 
preserved.

If you need a special kind of suit to dress up a class
of models  of which your structure is a member,
you may not get a precise fit: some members of the
class are excluded, or perhaps some additional members
are included.  Whether this is desirable depends on the
party for which one is dressing up.

The short answer is : it depends.  If you are looking
at alternative axiomatizations for your class, then why?
Do you need a term rewriting system to work on it?
Is recursive axiomatizability sufficient?  Do you need
a mixed presentation of a second order axiom and
one or two modifying first order axioms?  Are you
trying to fit your class in some poset of defined classes?

Shape does matter.  I can't tell you why before you tell
me enough motivation.

Comment: That said, we could use more descriptions in iambic pentameters...

Comment: the motivation is to generalize theorems of varieties of monoid of Reiterman and Eilenberg to more general structures. I don't know whether structures with this kind of axioms are valid, or if I have to restrict to structures defined only via equations without implication. Even more precisely, I want monoids to be quipped with an explicit operator omega, which is required to correspond to idempotent power in finite structures.