# $GL_n(\Bbb Z_p)$ conjugacy classes in a $GL_n(\Bbb Q_p)$ conjugacy class

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups

It is easy to classify conjugacy classes in $GL_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ by linear algebra. How to classify $GL_n(\Bbb Z_p)$ conjugacy classes in a $GL_n(\Bbb Q_p)$ conjugacy class? For example, for general matrix $A \in GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$, how many $X \in GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$ are  $GL_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ conjugated to $A$ up to $GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$ conjugaction? In some cases it is finite, is it always finite?

Motivation: when counting invariant lattices, one comes across such problems.

Edit: could we find some numerical invariants that distinguish different $\Bbb Z_p-$ conjugacy classes?

Comment: One way to proceed is to multiply the ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{Q}_{p})$ matrix through by an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ of minimal valuation to make it integral. Then two such matrices which are conjugate in ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ must have the same Smith normal form. I think people like Reiner and Zassenhaus (and maybe others before) have worked out this problem in detail.

Comment: Note that this conjugation classification (in either sense) commutes with adding scalars, so the classification of conjugacy classes in $M_n$ boils down to that in $GL_n$. So, considering conjugacy classes in $M_n$ is not harder; on the other hand it is a nicer setting, since it's a linear action.

Comment: For n=2 you can explicitly answer your question! https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90370/conjugation-in-gln-p-adic-setting/90397#90397

Comment: @TommasoCenteleghe Given two matrices in $\mathrm{M}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, is it possible to find an explicit integer $k \geq 1$ such that the matrices are conjugate over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if and only they are conjugate over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and over $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$? I guess such a $k$ could be related to the $p$-adic distance between two roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Regarding your edit: of course: there's the conjugacy class modulo $p^n$. Say, the characteristic polynomial modulo $p^n$, if you want a "computable" object and if you're primarily interested in semisimple elements.

Comment: Btw the question is ticked answer, so I'm not sure it makes sense to edit it asking more questions.

Comment: @YCor thank you! I am just a little curious, I will ask another question instead.

Comment: Yes. Maybe the last question takes more place at Math Stackexchange.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault : Maranda had results of this nature on your question above ( mentioned in various surveys by Reiner)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes if $A \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is semisimple.

We may think of a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-lattice of rank $n$ endowed with a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-linear endomorphism: take the standard lattice $L=\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ endowed with the endomorphism $\varphi$ associated to $A$. Clearly, two matrices $A,A' \in M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ are $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$-conjugated if and only if the associated pairs $(L,\varphi)$ and $(L',\varphi')$ are isomorphic.

More formally, consider the algebra $R = \mathbb{Z}_p[A]$ inside $M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. Then $A$ gives rise to an $R$-module $M$ which is $\mathbb{Z}_p$-free of rank $n$. Note that if $A' \in M_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is another matrix which is $\mathbb{Q}_p$-conjugated to $A$ then the algebras $\mathbb{Z}_p[A]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p[A']$ are isomorphic, as they are both isomorphic to $R = \mathbb{Z}_p[X]/(\mu)$ where $\mu$ denotes the minimal polynomial. However, the associated $R$-modules $M$ and $M'$ need not be isomorphic. In fact, they are if and only if $A$ and $A'$ are $\mathbb{Z}_p$-conjugated.

So the problem reduces to classifying the $R$-modules which are $\mathbb{Z}_p$-free of rank $n$ up to isomorphism. In the semisimple case, the following theorem of Jordan-Zassenhaus gives a positive answer to your third question.

> **Theorem** (Jordan-Zassenhaus). Let $K$ be a local or global field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $L$ be a (commutative) semisimple $K$-algebra, and let $R$ be an $\mathcal{O}_K$-order in $L$. Then for any integer $n \geq 1$, the set of isomorphism classes of $R$-modules which are $\mathcal{O}_K$-lattices of rank $\leq n$ is finite.

The case at hand follows by taking $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$, $L=\mathbb{Q}_p[X]/(\mu)$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/(\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a squarefree polynomial. A proof of the Jordan-Zassenhaus theorem is given in Reiner, *Maximal orders*, (26.4), p. 228. It is stated only for global fields, but you can check it also holds for local fields.

**EDIT.** The proof is not difficult: first one treats the case where $R$ is a maximal order, which is clear since it is a product of discrete valuation rings (hence PIDs). If $R' \subset R$ is an arbitrary order and $M'$ is an $R'$-lattice then there are only finitely many possibilities for $M=M' \otimes_{R'} R$, and since $p^N M \subset M' \subset M$ there are only finitely many possibilities for $M'$. So we get the finiteness.

Regarding the question of an explicit classification, you may be interested by Marseglia's article [*Computing the ideal class monoid of an order*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09671), where he gives algorithms to compute explicit representatives (in the global case).

**EDIT 2**. Another article giving an algorithm in the global case appeared on the arXiv today: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.06190

Answer (score 15):

*Is it always finite?* No.

The matrices $u_n=\begin{pmatrix}1 & p^n\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ are all conjugate in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$, and pairwise non-conjugate in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$.

Indeed, a matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ conjugating $u_n$ to $u_{n+m}$, for $m\ge 1$, is necessarily of the form $\begin{pmatrix}p^m\lambda & p^m\lambda\mu\\0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$ for scalars $\lambda\neq 0$, $\mu$. If it is in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$, the determinant $p^m\lambda^2$ has to be of valuation $0$, hence $\lambda$ has valuation $-m/2<0$ and $p^m\lambda$ has valuation $m/2>0$, and hence the trace $\lambda+p^m\lambda$ also has valuation $-m/2$, contradiction since the trace should be in $\mathbf{Z}_p$.

I'd be more optimistic for semisimple conjugacy classes.

---

Since François proved the finiteness for semisimple conjugacy classes, let me complete the proof of the converse: namely that if the $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbf{Q}_p)$-conjugacy class of $A\in M_d(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ splits into finitely many $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbf{Z}_p)$-conjugacy classes, then $A$ is semisimple.

Indeed, first if $P$ is a nonzero polynomial, the intersection of $\mathrm{Ker}(P(A))$ with $\mathbf{Z}_p^d$ is a direct summand of the latter as $\mathbf{Z}_p$-module. Hence, up to conjugation by some element of $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbf{Z}_p)$, we can suppose that $A$ is block-upper triangular $$A=\begin{pmatrix} A_1 & \dots &\\ 0 & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 &A_k\end{pmatrix}$$ such that for each diagonal block $A_i$ there is some irreducible polynomial $P_i$ over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ such that $P_i(A_i)$. Let $A'$ be the block-diagonal matrix with the same diagonal blocks $A_i$, so $A'$ is semisimple. Let $u$ be the diagonal matrix that equals $p^{k-i}$ on the $i$-th block. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}u^iAu^{-i}=A'$.

Assume the finiteness property. Since the $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbf{Z}_p)$-conjugacy classes are compact and there are finitely many in the $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbf{Q}_p)$-conjugacy class $\mathcal{C}$ of $A$, we deduce that they are open in $\mathcal{C}$. In particular, for $n$ large enough, $u^iAu^{-i}$ belongs to the $\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbf{Z}_p)$-conjugacy class of $A'$. This proves that $A$ is semisimple.

Comment: PS: there's a another argument to see that they're not conjugate: $u_n$ has a $p^n$-root in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$, but no $p^{n+1}$-root therein. Indeed, the $k$-roots of a matrix $e_{12}(x)=1+xE_{12}$, $x\neq 0$, in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$, all have the form $te_{12}(x/k)$ for some $k$-root of unity $t$.

Comment: It might be easier to note that $u_{n} -I$ is certainly not conjugate to $u_{m} -I$ when m and n are different.

Comment: Yet another argument: if $u_n$ and $u_{n'}$ are conjugate in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ with $n<n'$ then they are conjugate in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/p^{n+1})$ which is clearly impossible.